# How to load all files in a subdirectories using rollup without require statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, rollup, rollupjs

I have a large amount of javascript files in src/, I don't want to manually go in and require all my files.

```
|- /src
   |- a.js
   |- b.js
   |- c.js
   |- more.js
   | - index.js
```

**index.js**

```
import a from 'a.js'
import a from 'b.js'
import a from 'c.js'
//import more

export default {
  a,
  b,
  c,
  // more
}
```

Is there a way to do this with rollup or a plugin that someone has written to do this?

*English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.*

Comment: If you do not require them, roll up will remove unused code automagically which is a good point of rollup. If you don't mind using other try using gulp minify (https://codehangar.io/concatenate-and-minify-javascript-with-gulp/)[this] tut might help you.

Answer (score 1):

When you export a module it is automatically imported, so you can do:

```
export * from 'a.js';
export * from 'b.js';
// ...
```

If you don't need to import those modules later, but just include them in the bundle, you can import them like this:

```
import 'a.js';
import 'b.js';
```

And so on.

You can also take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-glob-import.